# Hide the url of pdf document opened in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to hide the url of a pdf document which has opened in the browser by clicking the link to pdf ?

If simply saying my need is: "**There must be no way for the user to find the pdf link. He can only see the content of pdf**"

Comment: Open it in an iframe? Not all browsers will open a pdf anyway, so it might be downloaded

Comment: But on inspecting the element it will be visible. Right?

Comment: if you open it in an iframe i can still get the URL - are you using MVC or HMVC pattern?

Comment: Yes it will. What are you trying to acheieve? If its restricted access, you can server the file via php with the correct headers

Comment: Why do you need to do so?

Comment: See my 1st point - some browsers will just download the file however you serve it. If thats not acceptable, then PDF is not the solution.

Comment: @pjp The data shown in the pdf is a ticket. So it should not be available for download. Just to see.

Comment: even then, what's the point? If I dont allow for download, there's always browser save option, print screen, and browser extensions like evernote or screencapture. And what kind of ticket should only be seen and not printed or downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In order for the user to see the PDF, the PDF data must be sent to the user's browser.

For the PDF data to be sent to the browser, you have to tell the browser where the PDF is.

Anything you tell the browser, you also tell the user (because the user controls the browser — to the point of having access to the source code for several browsers — and you do not).

---

You can mess around with temporary URIs, cookie based authentication, and so on. That probably won't do you much good though as the user can always save the PDF and republish it elsewhere.